# Facebook like plugin with Multi Option-Needed

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, facebook

i need to integrate facebook like button with some of additional features.

those are..

- every article/post has a 'Like' button (so that using this, when someone clicks 'Like' it'll appear in their Facebook news feed and add them to my Facebook page count direct from within my site)

please help me to get all these features with like button. is there any plugin done? or how to achieve from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the multi-like thing, but I use my plugin [Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/) for this sort of thing. It has some features that might help you out.

1. The Like module lets you add the Like button to all the posts and such.
2. The Fan Box widget lets you add a fan box to your sidebar. That like button in the Fan Box (Like box) is actually for your Facebook Page. When somebody likes it, then they're liking your page on FB.
3. The Publish module lets your posts get published to your Facebook Page automatically, and users who have liked your page will thus see your new posts appear in their home streams.

I recommend using the beta version of the plugin, it tends to work better and is getting very near release:
http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/simple-facebook-connect/branches/new-sfc/

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the like button works.you like a post then the count goes for that posts, if you you want someone to be counted in your FaceBook page they need to like that FaceBook page as well.

Comment: it's not possible?

Comment: Not in a legal way, no.

Comment: @:Bainternet: why not we develop like this one? both are same concept(like or dislike).so we need to do is, one button with update of  two functions.1 for posts & 2nd for facebook page.

Comment: Because It's illegal andagainst Facebook's TOS because when a person likes your post, you can't assume he likes you page. also known as clickJacking.

Comment: thanks for your information  @Bainternet: you are always great.+1 for your great support.

Comment: Glad I could help buddy.

Answer (score -1):

If you add any Like/ Social plugin you can add buttons for Facebook-Like, Twitter-Tweet. LinkedIn-Share.

When ANY visitor likes, shares, tweets the page/post. The count is added dynamically.

The Likes and Shares are posted on their Facebook Profile also.

1 of many plugins with this feature: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like/screenshots/